# URL shared in comment of document

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a problem that I want to get shared url of comment in document with my c# code. But I can't find any property or way to get it
Please help me know. Can I get it in c# code? and how to get?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be an API endpoint that allows you to do this, it was confirmed in a GitHub issue linked below:

[Can i get the link that link to comment?](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3045)

Comment: thank you. So, does any way can I navigate to specified comment?

Comment: When you add a comment to a Word document and tag another person, they receive an email with a link to that comment. Sadly, there is no API endpoint to fetch this sort of link. You may be able to craft the link yourself, if you can understand the URL variables and are able to get those values yourself. It's doesn't appear to be documented.

Comment: thank you so much. But the URL variables are encode and sadly I can't understand it :(

Comment: Yes, as stated in the answer, I don't really think this is possible.